# How can I model a skirt?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I’m a Blender beginner and I was just wondering if anyone could tell me how to make a skirt similar to the one in the picture below, just for extra background info cylinders were used to create the skirt. How do I model a cylinder to resemble the shape of a skirt. Thanks for the help, if someone answers! :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Likes Sims! Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. It's helpful for us if you can provide a minimal working example, or something that shows what you tried. We can then build upon your approach or explain any potential errors.

Answer (score 33):

1. Add a circle.
2. Add a subdivision surface modifier.
3. With all vertices selected, perform the *Checker Deselect* operation to select every 2nd vertex.
4. Scale the selected vertices inwards.
5. Select all and extrude them.
6. Select the resulting rings with <kbd>Alt</kbd> clicks and scale them accordingly.

[image: process]

Comment: I didn't know that this checker deselect exists. It seems super useful and no longer doing it manually lol

Comment: there is also "select previous/next active" that helps a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO5-RB66tdU

Comment: The last fold is a really nice touch! Thanks for showing us the technique.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to @Leander answer, you can use "cloth" simulation to give some custom real shape to the mesh (there are also fake legs inside the skirt as collision to generate additional shapes)

[image]