# How can I make a gown?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I was just wondering on how I could make skirts like as seen in the pictures below.
All ideas help! And I’m not very knowledgeable in blender so all help is appreciated. Thank you! :)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloth - Cloth interactions in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64115/cloth-cloth-interactions-in-blender)

Comment: Truthfully, the linked post doesn't even completely answer its own OPs question, as evidenced by the appearance of a follow up inquiry in the comments section which completely failed to get any further input.

Comment: here maybe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181387/how-can-i-model-a-skirt